# ¿Como insertar imagen a mysql con php?

Tags: php, mysql, blob

Tengo una duda. He tratado de insertar una imagen con php con exito pero al aplicar prepare statement la imagen o no se inserta o se inserta dañada y no se puede visualizar.
Por lo que vi mi error esta en bind_param() ya probe pasandolo como tipo de caracteres "s" y "b".
Hay algo que pueda hacer o deba leer para ejecutar sin problemas el codigo?

```
 $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
 $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
```

Dejo el metodo utilizado para obtener la imagen ↑

Codigo PHP completo

```
 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
        $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
        $biografia = $_POST["biografia"];
        $sexo = $_POST["sexo"];
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        if($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] !== ""){
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
            // die($check);
            if($check !== false){
                $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
                try{
                    include "conexion.php";
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO perfiles(nombre_perfil,usuario_perfil,biografia_perfil,sexo_perfil,image,cuenta_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssssbi", $nombre, $usuario, $biografia, $sexo, $imgContent, $id);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $insertId = $stmt->insert_id;
                    $respuesta = array(
                        "respuesta"=>"exito",
                        "datos"=>$insertId
                    );
                    $stmt->close();
                    $conn->close();
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
                    
                }
                die(json_encode($respuesta));
            }
    
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para insertar una imagen como blob varias cosas deben cumplirse primero

- El tipo de campo donde insertaras el valor en la tabla mysql debe ser de tipo `blob`
- Enviar el contenido binario de la imagen usando `$statement->bind_param()` con el tipo blob (`b`). Ejemplo `$stmt->bind_param('ib', $fileid, file_get_contents($image))`
- Si la imagen es mas grande que el tamaño máximo de paquete (`max_allowed_packet` 16MB por defecto), se deberia enviar usando `$statement->send_long_data()`.

Este ejemplo se basa en el de la documentación de PHP (https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php)

```
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO images (id, image) VALUES (?, ?)");
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param("ib", 1234, $null);
$fp = fopen($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "r");
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $stmt->send_long_data(0, fread($fp, 8192));
}
fclose($fp);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Otro metodo de almacenar imagenes es solo copiar la imagen a una ruta fija, asignarle un nombre unico en dicha ruta, y solo almacenar la ruta relativa en la base de datos. Este seria un ejemplo (puedes usar otro metodo para generar un id unico y elegir una ruta diferente de uploads)

```
// generar id unico 
$imageid = uniqid("img", true)
// mover archivo a uploads
$UPLOADPATH="./uploads";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"$UPLOADPATH/$imageid");
// almacenar en BD el id y/o la ruta de almacenaje
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO images (id, image_id, image_path) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("iss", $imageid, "$UPLOADPATH/$imageid");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: La primera forma intente varias veces.. Lo acabo de intentar ahora, y como dije se inserta todo (formulario con nombre, apellido, imagen, etc) menos la imagen. En mysql no me figura nada en el campo, y la imagen no supera los 50 kb jajaj.. investigo la otra forma y te dejo el codigo que use por si notas algo que yo no :(

Comment: @FedericoNuñez Cuando dices no me figura nada te refieres a un campo en NULL? puede que la vista no te muestre los campos BLOB directamente, donde estas viendo la data o como la obtienes de vuelta?

Comment: No se si tendra algo que ver pero lo tengo como LONGBLOB y a nada me refiero como si tomara los demas registros de insert pero justamente el que va con el blob se pasa vacio(en mysql no hay nada, solo los otros datos del formulario) como si no lo agregara en el insert, ni error figura.. Al final lo pude solucionar sin bind_param().. Directamente puse las variables en VALUE(), no se si al hacerlo de esta forma tengo desventajas pero de igual forma me re ayudaste :)